# How to make GRUB on HD boot a bootable USBDrive or from a `.iso` on USBDrive?

Tags: centos, grub2, grub, boot-loader

I'm currently struggling with a project where I need to make it boot from a bootable USBDrive using GRUB. (alternatively I could make a NTFS USBDrive with the raw `.iso` file) When I enter GRUB's command line it can't see the USB there, I only see the HD `(hd0)` and the main partition `(hd0,msdos1)`.

I already tried just guessing and creating a `menuentry` for `(hd1,..)`, but as you may expect, this didn't work.

**Keep in mind that I can't just change the boot sequence on the BIOS itself, even though BIOS recognizes the USBDrive.**

Am I missing something? Should GRUB already recognize it automatically?
I'm totally open to new ideas.

PS: Even though I'm not using Ubuntu, [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromUSB) they explain how to do something pretty similar to what I want.

PS2: It's a UEFI system.

Comment: Are you trying to boot an install, a live installer, or an ISO on USB drive. Is grub installed to USB drive? I primarily use Ubuntu but boot full installs on flash drives, now. I used to have smaller drives and just installed grub2 in UEFI mode, and used grub2's loopmount to boot ISO directly. Getting drive & path correct in boot stanza often biggest issue. Boot drive is always hd0, but somethings stanza has hd1 or hd2 and I have to manually edit as it boot to make it work.

Comment: What Linux distro and version is it? Or is it a custom system that you have created? See also the following links: [Grub2/ISOBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot) and [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) and links from those links.

Comment: the UEFI system may have the USB drive blacklisted

Comment: @oldfred I tried with both the iso and a live installer. How can I check if grub is installed on the USB Drive? Or how to do it? if it's only a .iso file?

Comment: @sudodus Will check those links. It's an RHEL 7, quite outdated :)

Comment: You cannot copy an ISO file to a flash drive & have it be bootable. You have to use install tools to extract ISO and make it a bootable flash drive.

Comment: If an old ISO, it just may not work as newer hardware needs newer kernel & drivers.

Comment: @Paiusco, Those links are useful to show in general terms what to do with grub, but remember that they talk about Ubuntu, and things must be modify to match the boot structure of RHEL.